# SimpleAdapter - переодическое добовление данных

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handlers

Здравствуйте. Мой вопрос заключается в следующем:
Имеется SimpleAdapter, в который подгружаются сообщения с сервера. В адаптере, методом (`Parcelable state = sList.onSaveInstanceState(); и  sList.onRestoreInstanceState(state);`) я сохраняю текущую позицию скролла, так как адаптер обновляет данные каждые 5сек. Т.е. мой адаптер постоянно пересоздаётся, а мне этого не надо. Я хочу сделать так... 
Json'ом каждые 5 сек проверять на наличие нового сообщения, и если оно есть, то вытащить это сообщение и добавить его уже в существующий адаптер. Как я понимаю, нужно создать отдельный класс AsyncTask, который будет посылать запросы каждые 5 сек. Сделал, вытащил данные (пишутся в логах)... но как их теперь добавить в существующий адаптер?

Обновляю данные handler'om, в методе FriendMsgLoad(), находится сам AsynkTask отправляющий запрос через HttpURLConnection.

```
class RefreshActivity extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
                FriendMsgLoad friendMsgLoad = new FriendMsgLoad();
                friendMsgLoad.execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: вы можете добавить данные в список (`List<>`), который вы используете для адаптера, и вызвать у адаптера `notifyDataSetChanged()`. При этом вам ненужно пересоздавать адаптер

Comment: По сути я так и делаю, в `data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();` добовляю данные, загоняю их в мап, но как только вызываю `notifyDataSetChanged` выходит ошибка NullPointerException

Comment: Значит что-то делаете не правильно. В ошибке указано, на какой строке она возникает, и изза чего. Смотрите стактрейс ошибки, или как минимум покажите его.

Comment: Я использую 2 класса. В первом у меня находится сам адаптер а во втором сетевой запрос. `String[] from = {LV_MSGID, LV_MSG, LV_USID_MSG, LV_MSG_TIME};
int[] to = {R.id.id_msg, R.id.msg, R.id.id_msg_user, R.id.msg_time};
new FriendMsgActivity().dataChanged(data, from, to);` после сетевого запроса я передаю данные `data` в метод `dataChanged` и пытаюсь присвоить адаптеру значения уже внутри класса `FriendMsgActivity`. Посе старта получаю ошибку `java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()`

Comment: Не покидайте меня пожалуйста :)

Comment: @sergei1094 не возможно сказать в чем именно у вас ошибка без исходных кодов

Comment: для начала, вы создаете экземпляр Activity через конструктор. Так нельзя. Только система должна их создавать. Поэтому вы и получаете ошибку. Но дальше - ничего не понятно. У вас какая-то ошибка, чтобы ее решить, вам придется показать ваш код. Или показывайте, или решайте проблему сами, на кофейной гуще вам никто тут гадать не будет